# JavaScript: Remove keys from json object

Tags: php, javascript, json

Example output from PHP:

```
{
    "RootName_0":{"Id":1,"ValId":1,"Value":"Colour","Text":"Blue"},
    "RootName_1":{"Id":1,"ValId":2,"Value":"Colour","Text":"Red"}
}
```

How can I use `Backbone.js` or `jQuery` to only have:

```
[
    {"Id":1,"ValId":1,"Value":"Colour","Text":"Blue"},
    {"Id":1,"ValId":2,"Value":"Colour","Text":"Red"}
]
```

If it's easier to use PHP to edit the JSON, then so be it.

Comment: Just fix your PHP output. Shouldn't be hard. That's silly JSON output in the first place, anyway!

Comment: The JSON output cannot be changed, it has to be changed after it has been generated.

Comment: Why's that then? Also please don't abuse commas like that ;(

Comment: You should be aware that if you do it in JavaScript, the order of enumeration isn't guaranteed, so your objects may not remain in their originally defined order. You'd need to enforce the order manually using the presumably sequential `RootName_n` keys, and foreknowledge of the last number.

Comment: ...I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9218253/1106925) with a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, in PHP it would be easy, just use `array_values()` on the initial array so that it 'forgets' the array indexes (which by the way, is what 'RootName_X' is called in your case:

```
$newvalue = array_values( (array)$value );
echo json_encode($newvalue);
```

---

In javascript, it's a bit trickier, but it would be on the lines of:

```
var newvalue = [];
for(var root in value)
   newvalue.push(value[root]);
```

---

The question title <s>is</s> was a bit confusing since these are certainly not *tags*.

Answer (score 2):

No need for jquery or Backbone:

```
var obj = {
    "RootName_0":{"Id":1,"ValId":1,"Value":"Colour","Text":"Blue"},
    "RootName_1":{"Id":1,"ValId":2,"Value":"Colour","Text":"Red"}
};
var colors = [];

for(var key in obj){
   colors.push(obj[key]);
};
```

The value you want is now in the `colors` array.

Answer (score 1):

Using ES5 (modern browsers) you could do:

```
Object.keys(received).map(function(key) {
  return received[key];
});
```

Basically, converting the object into an array of its keys, then replacing each key with the value.

Comment: Nice one! Very compact. However, he first needs to obtain a Javascript object from his JSON content.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I assumed the OP is already able to get the JSON (which is a piece of cake using jQuery). It's just a matter of running this inside the ajax callback.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, if `myFirstVar` contains the initial object, then do:

```
mySecondVar = [ myFirstVar.RootName_0, myFirstVar.RootName_1 ];
```

Comment: That's not particularly extensible.

Comment: Feel free to make it more generic. I was just showing the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Once the JSON has been parsed, do it using jQuery's [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map), and borrowing the global `Object` function...

```
var arr = $.map(obj,Object);
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you do it in JavaScript, you should be aware that the objects may not remain in their original order.

You can remedy this if the `RootName_n` keys are sequential, and you know the `n` of the last key.

```
var last_key = 20;

var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i <= last_key; i++) 
    arr.push( obj['RootName_' + i] );
```